# Drupal AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP status code: 200

Tags: ajax, drupal-7

I had Drupal 7 and when I want to delete user, an error occurs:

```
AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP status code: 200 Debug information below.
Path : /batch?id=1594&op=do 
StatusText: OK
ResponseText : #Screenshot
```

[image: #Screenshot]

Comment: How is that an error? 200 indicates an OK response.

Comment: what is your code, what is the callback. please provide info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a server error so Drupal send many request at once but the server have a miximum execution time. I suggested for my client to change it and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You have 'exit' or die() or "echo" placed somewhere in your template files. I had this issue multiple times and all times i had come across this problem. That's the only reason due to which ajax breaks because error is not displaying 200 code. That means that things are correct. Only issue is echo/die/exit placed at some unexpected place.